# Shell dash for loop skip first two arguments

Tags: shell

How to skip first two arguments using "$@" in shell dash and use the rest of arguments in for loop?

For example, I have something like `command --option file1 file2 file3`. I want to skip first two arguments and loop over all the files (any number of files).

I have tried using the following line:

```
files=$(echo "$@" | awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' | tr -d '\n')
```

However it does not provide a line of files, but something like `file1file2file3`.

I would like to be able to iterate over each file name individually later in the for loop:

```
for file in "$files"
do
    rm "./desktop/temp/$file"
done
```

Comment: You can't store an arbitrary list in a string in the first place. Use arrays instead (which, yes, means using bash or ksh instead of dash) when you want to store lists.

Comment: (The reason storing a list of filenames in a string is doomed to be buggy is that the set of characters you can have in a string is identical to the set of characters you can have in a single filename; so `one<newline>two` could be two separate files, or it could be just one file with a newline inside its name; your code has no way to tell the two cases apart).

Comment: For the same reason, `echo "$@"` loses information. `yourscript "argument one" "argument two"` creates the same output from `echo "$@"` as `yourscript "argument" "one two" "argument"` does; the information about where the argument boundaries are supposed to be is lost when you run that code.

Comment: ...mind, you _can_ deal with NUL-delimited lists in dash, if you're careful about it. `printf '%s\0' "$@"` works fine to generate a stream with a NUL between each arguments, and carefully-written `awk` can parse that stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that by "shell dash" you mean that you are using [Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell#dash), a light-weight shell that sticks to the Posix standard. Comparing to Bash, Dash is quite limited and doesn't offer functionalities like arrays or complex parameter substitutions like `${@:m:n}`.

I also assume that, by doing `files=$(echo "$@" | ...)` you know for sure that none of your arguments contains space characters.

That said, your issue is due to the `| tr -d '\n'` part which removes the end of line that serves as a word separator. That's why you get "file1file2file3".

But the whole command can be enhanced. Here is a better Posix-compatible way of doing this:

```
files=$(shift 2; printf '%s ' "$@")
```

(`shift` being done in a sub-shell, it doesn't affect the argument list in the current shell)

You may even do this:

```
(
    shift 2
    for file in "$@"; do
        rm "./desktop/temp/$file"
    done
)
```

(here the whole loop is executed in a subshell)

... or write a function:

```
rm_files()
{
    shift 2
    for file in "$@"; do
        rm "./desktop/temp/$file"
    done
}

rm_file "$@"
```

One last suggestion: is it really necessary to keep arguments 1 and 2 in the argument list? You could do something like:

```
arg1="$1"
arg2="$2"
shift 2
for file in "$@"; do
    rm "./desktop/temp/$file"
done
```

... and if you need all your arguments at once, you can do:

```
for arg in "$arg1" "$arg2" "$@"; do ...; done
```